# Extracting ordered results after running HTTP requests multiple times using a CSV data set config in JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I want to test a given HTTP request multiple times, say 25 times. Also, I have *n* number of payloads for the HTTP request body. So, I got around to add these n payloads to a CSV file and to populate the HTTP request using them. So each of the *n* HTTP requests has to be executed 25 times. How do I get the results to be ordered by the payload? In other words, how do I extract the 25 requests made per payload?

My current test plan looks like this! Note that there are 14 unique requests and a loop count of 25. But the results seem to be jumbled up. I want a sequential ordering per bulk of responses. Any help with this regard is highly appreciated. Sorry for the poor explanation of the problem. If the question needs further clarification let me know :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your "payload" as postfix for the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler label

For example if you have a `test.csv` file looking like:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

And the following [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup:

[image]

If you change your HTTP Request sampler name to `HTTP Request - ${payload}` the current value from the CSV file will be added to sampler label:

[image]

Similarly you can add:

- [__threadNum() function](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II) to display the number of current thread (virtual user)
- `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` special JMeter Variable to display the current iteration of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
- etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is exactly what I was looking for